# C - Problems Creating Dynamic Matrix Function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, dynamic

I had a dynamic matrix created in main, but since decided it was better to implement a function to make it easier to create more when necessary. I moved my code towards the function, yet not well enough.

As soon as I attempt to write to M[0][0] my program crashes.

This is how I compile (no errors):
gcc -Wall -std=c99 -o output.exe source.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void MakeMATRIX (int** MATRIX, int* ROW, int* COL);

int main()
{
int SIZE;
scanf("%d", &SIZE);

int** M = NULL;

MakeMATRIX(M, &SIZE, &SIZE);

---MORE CODE GOES HERE---

scanf("%d", &M[0][0]);

return 0;
}

void MakeMATRIX (int** MATRIX, int* ROW, int* COL)
{
MATRIX = (int **)malloc(*ROW * sizeof(int*));

for (int i = 0; i < *ROW; i++)
  {
  MATRIX[i] = (int *)malloc(*COL * sizeof(int));
  }
}
```

Comment: you must return the MATRIX pointer from the makeMatrix function and assign it to M, or else you are pointing at NULL.

Comment: oh that makes sense now that you pointed it out. I managed to fix it thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return allocated matrix from `MakeMatrics` function.

```
int ** MakeMATRIX (int** MATRIX, int* ROW, int* COL)
{
  MATRIX = (int **)malloc(*ROW * sizeof(int*));

  for (int i = 0; i < *ROW; i++)
  {
    MATRIX[i] = (int *)malloc(*COL * sizeof(int));
  }

  return MATRIX;
}
```

And in `main()`

```
M = MakeMATRIX(M, &SIZE, &SIZE);
```

Otherwise you can pass `&M` and allocated in `*MATRIX` rather than `MATRIX`.

With your code value of `M` will not change in `main()` as its passed by value, Even though its pointer, you are passing it as value.

And its assigned to `NULL` it will give segmentation fault when you try to dereference it.

Answer (score 0):

Local variables changed in a called function has no effect in the calling function. Here you are changing value of `MATRIX`, so address of `MATRIX` needs to passed to retain its value.

```
void MakeMATRIX (int*** MATRIX, int ROW, int COL) //value of ROW and COL seems fine to pass since they are not changed
{
*MATRIX = (int **)malloc(ROW * sizeof(int*));

for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
  {
  *MATRIX[i] = (int *)malloc(COL * sizeof(int));
  }
}
```

And in `main()`:

```
MakeMATRIX(&M, SIZE, SIZE);
```

---

*Another way* of doing this is returning `MATRIX`:

```
int** MakeMATRIX (int ROW, int COL)
{
int **MATRIX = (int **)malloc(ROW * sizeof(int*));

for (int i = 0; i < ROW; i++)
  {
  MATRIX[i] = (int *)malloc(COL * sizeof(int));
  }
}
```

So the `main()` would be:

```
int** M;

M=MakeMATRIX(SIZE, SIZE);
```